# Execute Chef recipe code if previous code block succeeds

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I want the second code to only execute if the first one returns a 0 status (succeeds).

```
execute 'make dir' do
   command 'mkdir foo'
   action :run
end
execute 'make dir2' do
 command 'mkdir bar'
 action :run
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using the native Chef resources for things like directory creation.  Shelling out should be avoided as much as possible, as it circumvents Chef's idempotence, among other problems.

Secondly, if your first resource fails, the chef-client will exit, so subsequent resources will obviously not get done, unless you add an attribute to ignore failure for the resource.

However, this is probably what you want here:

```
directory 'bar' do
  action :nothing
end

directory 'foo' do
  action :create
  notifies :create, 'directory[dir2]', :immediately
  ignore_failure true
end
```

Comment: `ignore_failure` is almost never what you want for anything :)

Comment: Yeah, I never use it for my production stuff, but *shrug*